# Why is the field value stored as a set?

Tags: django, django-models

When the input field value is saved to the db and I retrieve the same value for updating the field, I get the updated field as a set

Data when i retrieve from db, <QuerySet [{'id': 21,'book_title': 'pokolo', 'book_category': '0', 'book_type': 'F'}]>

Data after updating the retrieved field value,
<QuerySet [{'id': 21,'book_title': "('pokolo',)", 'book_category': '0', 'book_type': 'F'}]>

The book title is a CharField and is cleaned before sending to the db

Updating books

```py
def update_book(request)
    book_id        = request.POST.get('book_id')
    title          = request.POST.get('book_title')
    category       = request.POST.get('book_category')
    type           = request.POST.get('book_type')

    try:
        b=Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        b.book_title      = title,
        b.book_category   = category    
        b.book_type       = type        

        b.save()
    except Book.BookNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({book_id:"Book not found"})
```

Comment: Share the code where you update your value.

Comment: Typo: You have a `,` at the end of the line `b.book_title      = title,` this makes it a one tuple, remove that comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line where you update the field has a *comma*, for example something like:

```
#       trailing comma ↓
book.book_title = title,
book.save()
```

because of the trailing comma, Python will wrap this in a singleton tuple (a tuple with extactly *one* element), and when it is later converted to a string, it will thus show the comma.

You should thus remove the trailing comma, and work with:

```
#    no trailing comma ↓
book.book_title = title
book.save()
```